# Best way of selecting 8k+ rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, sql-server-2008

I have an excel sheet that contains more than 8k IDs. I have a table in SQL server that contains those IDs and related entries. What would be the best way to get those rows? The way I am doing right now is to use `export data` function from for the specific table using query:

`select * from table_name where uID in (ALL 8K IDs)`

Comment: do you need all the rows from the table or are there more than those 8k rows in your table?

Comment: There are 50k+ rows. Out of which, I would need these 8k rows. The ID for these rows come from a column in an excel/csv file.

Comment: post the data how it looks like ??? you want retrive 8k rows or value with 8k

Comment: He has 8k ids that he has to retrieve from table, those 8k ids are in a file so he has to read those in somehow, I would suggest creating a temporary table with the ids you read in and then joining on that table for the select

Comment: @mohan111 Consider this: You have 8k+ IDs for 50k+ rows in a table. What's the best  way to select such large no of rows?

Comment: "Best" is subjective here. Depends on whether you do it only once or every minute.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I understand, but as I mentioned in my question, I am looking for a better way than what i am attempting right now.

Comment: How are you getting the list of ids out of the excel and into sql server? Is this a one time thing or do you need it to perform multiple times?

Comment: @ZoharPeled It's a csv. I simply took out the column separated by comma.

Comment: So basically you are using copy-paste to get the list of ids? If so, then the **simplest** way to do it is using the IN operator like you did. However, using the IN operator with a large set does suffer from performance issues. This is why everybody wants to know if this is a one time thing or do you have to repeat it every once in a while.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for clarifying. I am looking for a solution with better performance. This has to be done on multiple environments, multiple times.

Comment: @Maxsteel you have no automated way of filling up the IN(etc...) List? are you just manually copy pasting it in there?

Comment: If you put the 8K IDs into a #TEMP db, the query becomes `select * from table_name where uID in (select id from #temp)`. Your biggest problem seems to be how to determine and store the 8K of IDs in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this has to be done multiple times I suggest using [bulk insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) from the csv file to a temporary sql table and then use inner join with this table.
Assuming your csv file contains the ids in a single row, (i.e 1,34,345,....),  something like this should do the trick:

```
-- create the temporary table
CREATE TABLE #CSVData 
(
    IdValue int
)
-- create a clustered index for this table (Note: this doesn't need to be unique)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_CSVData on #CSVData (IdValue ) 

-- insert the csv data to the table
BULK INSERT #CSVData
FROM 'c:\csvData.txt'
WITH
(
    ROWTERMINATOR = ','
)

-- select the data 
SELECT T.* 
FROM table_name T
INNER JOIN #CSVData ON(T.uId = IdValue)

-- cleanup (the index will be dropped with the table)
DROP TABLE #CSVData
```

One more link to look at is [This article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) by Pinal dave on sqlauthority.

Comment: Ha! I just posted a comment to this effect.

Comment: I ended up doing exact same thing. Thanks for your time and effort :)